# How to make flash light application in Java ME?

Tags: java-me

Trying to make a flash light application, I am not getting it working. This is my code:

```
public void setFlash(Controllable player) {
    FlashControl flashControl =
            (FlashControl) getControl(player, "javax.microedition.amms.control.camera.FlashControl");
    if (flashControl != null) {
        int[] supportedFlash = flashControl.getSupportedModes();
        if (supportedFlash != null && supportedFlash.length > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < supportedFlash.length; i++) {
                if (supportedFlash[i] == DESIRED_FLASH) {
                    try {
                        flashControl.setMode(DESIRED_FLASH);
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
                        // continue
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [JSR 234 documentation](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=234) FlashControl has six public constants:

- AUTO: The camera will autoflash according to the lighting condition
- AUTO_WITH_REDEYEREDUCE: The camera will autoflash according to the lighting conditions and if it flashes it will use red-eye reduction
- FILLIN: Reduced flash
- FORCE: Camera flash is on
- FORCE_WITH_REDEYEREDUCE: Camera flash is on and red-eye reduction is in use
- OFF: Camera flash is off

You should use FORCE or FORCE_WITH_REDEYEREDUCE